# OpenXML 2.5 - WordProcessing - How to copy the styles from template document when creating a new document?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a template document that has a few paragraphs and tables with some styles associated with them.

I need to select the elements from template document based on a sequence, and then append them to the body of my new document. Below is my code that does the copying. I somehow need to copy the styles associated with the elements as well. Although some styles get applied, things like font size and table borders are not getting copied onto the new document. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
   Dictionary<string, string> sequence = GetSequence();
            using (WordprocessingDocument templateDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(sourceFileLocation, false))
            {
                Body templateBody = templateDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                using (
                    WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(destinationFileLocation,
                        WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
                {
                    MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
                    mainPart.Document = new Document();
                    Body wordDocDocBody = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
                   //don't think the below two lines work as I intended.
                    ThemePart themePart1 = templateDocument.MainDocumentPart.ThemePart;
                    mainPart.AddPart(themePart1);

                    foreach (var item in sequence)
                    {
                     var block = templateBody.Elements().TakeWhile(x => x.InnerText == item.Key);
                        foreach (var blockItem in block)
                        {
                            wordDocBody.Append(blockItem.CloneNode(true));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code copies a style with a fixed name (in this case, a 'canned' table style) from one Word document to another.

```
void CopyTableStyles( WordprocessingDocument source, WordprocessingDocument destination )
        {
            var sourceStyles = source.MainDocumentPart.StyleDefinitionsPart.RootElement;
            var tableStyle = sourceStyles.Descendants<Style>()
                                .Where<Style>( s => s.StyleName.Val == "Light List - Accent 11")
                                .First<Style>();
            if ( tableStyle != null )
            {
                var destinationStyles = destination.MainDocumentPart.StyleDefinitionsPart.RootElement;
                destinationStyles.AppendChild( tableStyle.CloneNode( true ) );
                destination.MainDocumentPart.StyleDefinitionsPart.PutXDocument();
            }
            return;
        }
```

You should be able to work from here to make this more robust and fit you need.

Edit:  Sorry, PutXDocument is an extension method that was originally taken from one of Eric White's examples on the Open XML Developer site.

```
public static void PutXDocument(this OpenXmlPart part)
{
    XDocument xdoc = part.GetXDocument();
    if (xdoc != null)
    {
        // Serialize the XDocument object back to the Package.
        using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create( part.GetStream( FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write )))
        {
            xdoc.Save( xw );
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is in an OpenXmlPart static extension class in my current "bag of tricks" -- I suspect I haven't changed it since reading the blog post/examples provided by Mr. White.

Answer (score 0):

In this line: `var block = templateBody.Elements().TakeWhile(x => x.InnerText == item.Key);` you're selecting only the `Text` objects.  Therefore, the formatting is getting left out.  You will need to also copy the parents of this Text object to the new document.  You may need to copy `Paragraph` children to `Run` to `Text` for the formatting to copy over.

Comment: Your solution will only work partially. If styles have been applied to the text, the OP will have to reference those from the Styles.xml part and add them to the destination document as well.

Comment: From the context of my above code, before appending the blockItem to the body of destination document, do I need to create an object of type ParagraphProperties and clone the properties of the actual paragraph from the template document ? Thanks both.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for your question is going to be rather large, So I', only going to spell out what needs to be done, you can write code for that and get back if you're stuck.

As @tr4nc3 has mentioned, consider copying the parents to the `Text`, if you're copying an entire paragraph, copy the `Paragraph` object from source to destination else the `Run` object should suffice.

If there is a scenario where a Style has been applied to a paragraph then you'll have to get the `ParagraphStyle.Val` for that paragraph and use that reference to copy the `Style` object from `StylePart` to the Destination Object.

I know this a quite a handful of stuff that needs to be done but, if you use the [Open XML Productivity Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30425) it will make your life a lot easier.